# Using OutputFileStream("test.abc") in an Applet on a server is creating an new file in the folder of the browser

Tags: java, web, applet, relative-path

First, sorry for my bad english.

I'm not a pro in java and never programmed an applet before. So I'm trying to program a little game for my website. In this game I want a picture as background so i tried to load it with:

```
Image im = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(path);
```

That throws a FileNotFoundException, so I tried to creat a new file with FileOutputStream("test.abc"), to look where it will be created. I did this and it was created in my local firefox folder. 
So how can I load the picture from a folder on the server?

Comment: The code appears right. What is the value of the path agrument in getImage()?

Comment: Confirm if the file exists in the right path on the server.

Comment: Yeah, it does. I checked it 100 times.

Comment: What's the *question?* How to load an image, or why does FileOutputStream create local files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I did this and it was created in my local firefox folder.

Of course it did. Why are you surprised? FileOutputStream doesn't speak HTTP to your server. It talks to a local file system.

> So how can I load the picture from a folder on the server?

`getCodeBase()+"/back.jpg"` should work *if* `back.jpg` is in the directory referred to by `getCodeBase()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a BG image it might as well be an [embedded resource](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info).  To 'embed' it, include it in one of the Jars of the applet, then access it according to the link above.

You might also consider deploying a frame (as opposed to an applet) from a link using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  That provides lower development/maintenance time and a much better user experience.